# Need to render form in footer only on home page. Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a _layout.cshtml page that renders the header and footer for every page. In my _footer.cshtml I have a newsletter form. As of right now, the newsletter form is rendering on every page. I need it to only render on the home page footer.

My thought for a solution is just using an if statement that checks if we're on the home page:

```
 @if(Request.RawUrl == "/")
 {
      Newsletter form
 }
```

My problem with this is that whenever I try to get the url, it's the same on every page.

For example:

the url might be https://something.com/checkout, so Request.RawUrl gets /checkout. But when I navigate to https://something.com, Request.RawUrl still gets /checkout. **How can I get the actual path of the page?**

I've tried using just about every request.url option I can find. None of them get the actual url path of the page after being redirected to a new page. Just whatever the original one was.

Comment: The better way to do this is to make use of `Sections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a ViewModel instead of querying the Request object.